# How to convert from clock hour/minute to Degree inObjective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

```
1.30 AM -> 45 Degree
0 AM -> 90 Degree
3 AM or 15 PM -> 0 Degree
9:00 AM -> 180 Degree
```

Cound you please show me formular to calculate NSDate to Degree ?

Comment: This seems rather trivial, how many degrees is an hour since a whole quadrant is 12 hours? Then you're done.

Comment: 1 hour 30 Degree, so 2 PM -> 60 Degree ?

Comment: Let's see what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the convention is that every 1 hour corresponds to 360/24 = 15 degrees. So 3AM * 15 = 45degrees. 2pm * 15 = 30 degrees.
However, if you set your zero at 3AM as you are doing with your numbers, then your formula would be (3-hours)*360/12. So 3AM = 0 degrees. 1.5 = 45 degrees. 0am = 90degrees. 9am = -180degrees.